# Ignore Routes to {resource}/Services/*.svc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to ignore every URL that is of the form `http://domain/Services/{serviceName}.svc/mex?wsdl` so I added the following to the top of my `RegisterRoutes` method in the `Global.asax` file:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}/Services");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}/Services/{pathInfo}.svc");
```

This did not solve the problem and it is still trying to get resolved by the default route which obviously fails.

The problem started when I try to browse a WCF service (this works), but then when I try to view its metadata, I get a `404 Error`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

routes.IgnoreRoute("{Services}/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: Nope, did not work. I get the following exception when I try to browse the service: `A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.
`

Comment: try this instead routes.IgnoreRoute("{Services}/{*pathInfo}"); - anything in the services folder will be ignored.

Comment: Awesome! The last one worked! Thanks alot. Please edit your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: unfortunately, this solved an issue but caused another. Now all the calls that were handler by the default route are returning a 404 error. Do you think I could add some constraints to the default route instead of adding the ignore route instruction? Like can I tell the default route to handler all requests except those that have the `{Services}` token inside it?